# Modify rails link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found somewhere what `:back` option in `link_to` helper has this code:

`@controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] || 'javascript:history.back()`

where i can change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually uses `url_for` helper. You can override it in a helper. For example, put it in application_helper.rb in your Rails app:

```
def url_for(options = {})
  if options == :back
    # replace this with your code
    controller.request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] || 'javascript:history.back()'
  else
    super(options)
  end
end
```